Shiny app in R with two dataframes linked to one menu
I have four datasets that I have shaped and combined into combined_data. I'm able to get my shiny app to work with this dataset, showing data from each separate dataframe as a different coloured line.
The other dataset that I am attempting to include separately has the same input values as combined_data, but a different y-axis scale. I've tried to add it with plotly, but am getting the error [Object object].
I wanted to be able to see the data from eq08_total_employed on my shiny app as well, but got the error Object:object when the app popped up.
Sample data:
combined_data <- data.frame(
  Occupation = c("Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Doctor", "Doctor", "Doctor"),
  quarter = c("Q2022q1", "Q2022q2", "Q2022q3", "Q2022q1", "Q2022q2", "Q2022q3"),
  occupation_per_1000 = c(5.1, 5.3, 5.2, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7)
)

EQ08_employed_total <- data.frame(
  Occupation = c("Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Doctor", "Doctor", "Doctor"),
  quarter = c("Q2022q1", "Q2022q2", "Q2022q3", "Q2022q1", "Q2022q2", "Q2022q3"),
  total_employed = c(1200, 1250, 1300, 1600, 1650, 1700)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Occupation Data Visualization"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("occupation", "Select Occupation:", choices = unique(combined_data$Occupation))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("linePlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$linePlot <- renderPlotly({
    
    # Filter the datasets based on the selected occupation
    combined_filtered <- combined_data %>%`
      filter(Occupation == input$occupation)
    
   eq08_employed_total <- EQ08_employed_total %>%
      filter(Occupation == input$occupation)
    
    # Create the Plotly object with two y-axes
    p <- plot_ly() %>%
      add_trace(
        data = combined_filtered,
        x = ~quarter,
        y = ~occupation_per_1000,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'Occupation per 1000',
        line = list(color = 'blue')
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        data = eq08_employed_total,
        x = ~quarter,
        y = ~total_employed,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'Total Employed',
        yaxis = 'y2',
        line = list(color = 'green')
      ) %>%
      layout(
        title = paste("Occupation Data for", input$occupation),
        xaxis = list(title = "Quarter"),
        yaxis = list(
          title = "Occupation per 1000",
          autorange = TRUE
        ),
        yaxis2 = list(
          title = "Total Employed",
          overlaying = "y",
          side = "right"
        ),
        margin = list(t = 60, b = 40, l = 60, r = 60)
      )
    
    p
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Your app runs fine on my machine without any error
